# Windows File Explorer: When going back, restore the previous scroll position?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

When the directory contains lots of files (that is, the scroll bar is showing), if I double-click a directory to navigate into and then go back to the previous directory, Windows File Explorer does not maintain the original scrolling position, but the directory I had clicked gets placed at the end of the listing.

For example, in the screenshot below, I was viewing `C:\Windows`, and then navigated into `C:\Windows\ShellComponents`, and then went back to `C:\Windows`. Note that the `ShellComponents` was originally in the middle (left image), but now is at the bottom (right image).

This behaviour is very annoying when I have to search the sub-directories. Is this a bug or an intended behaviour? Can I force it to keep the previous scrolling position?

[image: Before] -> [image: After]

Comment: Explorer Scrolling has been screwed up since W7, I guess Microsoft has no desire to fix it.

Comment: Yes - I agree. Consider xPlorer2 (zabkat) as it maintains its configurations. You can get a trial and see.